# bash, script for using string

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to execute 2 commands in one line:

```
git add filename
git commit -m "A message"
```

I'm trying this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./gac FILENAME COMMIT_MESSAGE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
git add $1
git commit -m $2
```

But my problem is I have to write all the COMMIT_MESSAGE together, without spaces. How can I fix it?

I want ot use the script like this:

```
gac filename "my message with spaces and double quotes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try qouting the `$2` like so

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./gac FILENAME COMMIT_MESSAGE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
git add $1
git commit -m "$2" # <-- here
```

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: ./gac FILENAME COMMIT_MESSAGE" >&2
  exit 1
fi
git add $1
git commit -m   echo "$2"` <-- like this?

Comment: yes, exactly. It worked for me